# SharePoint Custom Action on Addanapp.aspx not executing

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-online, custom-action

I've started to try and learn Custom Actions and as a bit of a test, I want to hide some elements on the addanapp.aspx page.

Individually, I have managed to test each line of the elements in a Chrome Developer Tools session and they hide as expected when executed individually. However, none of them are firing when I access the addanapp.aspx page. I've registered a custom action and am pointing it to the file with the code shown below.

Am I missing something obvious? I tried remarking out the SP.SOD line and *some* of the ID elements were hidden, but not all.

```
var jQuery = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js";

// Is MDS enabled?
if ("undefined" != typeof g_MinimalDownload && g_MinimalDownload && (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()).endsWith("/_layouts/15/start.aspx") && "undefined" != typeof asyncDeltaManager) {
// Register script for MDS if possible
RegisterModuleInit("hideAddanApp.js", JavaScript_Embed); //MDS registration
JavaScript_Embed(); //non MDS run
} else {
JavaScript_Embed();
}

function JavaScript_Embed() {

loadScript(jQuery, function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { SetStatusBar(message); }, 'sp.js');
// Customize the addanapp.aspx page
if (IsOnPage("addanapp.aspx")) {
//hide the search apps field and label
$("#idStorefrontHeader").hide();
$("#idStorefrontListManageSorts").hide();
$("#idStorefrontListManageFilter").hide();
}
});
});
}

function SetStatusBar(message) {
var strStatusID = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Information : ", message, true);
SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(strStatusID, "yellow");
}

function IsOnPage(pageName) {
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(pageName.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I managed to get this working - for the most part yesterday.

Instead of using a block of code in one Custom Action, I re-factored the code into small, bite-size chunks using the Add-PnPJavaScriptBlock and Add-PnPJavaScriptLink Shell commands.